# Regular expression when one of my selection is followed by space or is empty

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have this regex:

```
^((?:[\d,//\½\¼]+\s(?:dag|g|little|l|liter)?(?=\s))|)(.*)
```

If I input: 1 liter milk I get a match. If I enter 1 egg I do not get a match in $1. Why not?

How do I tell that the condition should be liter + space, l + space etc... or only number?

I can make words like (dag |g |little |l |liter ) without the (?=\s) but that is kind of stupid... To write space after every word...

Example:

Input string:

```
30 dag beans
around 1,5 liter of water
1 liter
1 egg
1/2 teaspoon water
```

Output:

```
30 dag
around 1,5 liter of water
1 liter
1
1/2
```

Comment: wrap around parentesis: `((?:dag|g|little|l|liter)\s)?`

Comment: Check [`/^(\d+(?:\/\d+)?)\s(dag|liter|egg|teaspoon)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/fC2cF9/7)

Comment: Thanx, but this way I get 1 egg out of the regex and 1/2 teaspoon water

Comment: Tushar: not working. I get only 30 without "dag" out.

Comment: Check [`^((?:\d+(?:\/\d+)?)\s(?:dag|liter)?|.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/fC2cF9/8). This gives exact match like shown in output. Check right middle section called `Match Information` to see matches.

Comment: The wrap around parenthesis works! Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Check
[`^((?:\d+(?:\/\d+)?)\s(?:dag|liter)?|.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/fC2cF9/8). This gives exact match like shown in output. Check right middle section called `Match Information` to see matches.
                    – Tushar